# the trait bound `RuntimeOrigin: From<pallet_collective::RawOrigin<AccountId32, Instance2>>` is not satisfied

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, pallet-collective

This is my github repo [here](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/tree/staking-pallet-testing).

I am getting this issue. I try to look how `pallet_collective` implemented in substrate main branch runtime [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs) but I can't able to find any solution.

[image]

Someone please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/blob/e798e1095531be77a01e55f61d80846e3b466b33/runtime/src/lib.rs#L975

The compiler complained about "cannot find Instance2 and Instance3" because you only constructed `Instance1` in the runtime.